# using tables to represent system of equations

Tags: tables

I am currently using a tables to represent the system of equations.

an example is as follows:

[image]

I can only represent the matrix on the left but unable to represent the variables and R.H.S

My L.H.S is as follows

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\label{augSystem}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}  
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.4cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.4cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}| }
                \hline
                    & $A$            & $-b$    & $\bar{b} $    &    &             &                         \\[0.3cm] \hdashline
                    &                &         &               &    &             &                         \\[-0.4cm]
     $-A^{T}$       &                & $c$     & $-\bar{c}$    & I  &             &                         \\[0.7cm]\hdashline
      $b^{T}$       & -c             &         &$-\alpha$      &    & -1          &                         \\[0cm] \hdashline
$-\bar{b}^{T}$      & $\bar{c}^T$    &$\alpha$ &               &    &             & -1                      \\[0cm] \hdashline
                    &                &         &               &    &             &                         \\[-0.4cm]
  $-\bar{b}^{T}$    & $S$            &         &               & I  &             & -1                      \\[0.8cm] \hdashline
                    &                & $\rho$  &               &    & $\kappa$    &                         \\[0cm] \hdashline
                    &                &         & $\nu$         &    &             & $\theta$                \\[0cm] \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The variables are y, x, y, v, z, a, b and the rhs is r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your tables are all with math terms, I've used some `array`s, and I've nested them in a `tabular`.

For the vertical alignment, I've used some struts (= rules with no width) and some other tricks (maybe there are some better methods, that's the best I can do).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\rule[-\baselineskip]{0pt}{0pt}$}m{#1}<{$}}

\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\myvsp}{\vspace{-7pt}\newline}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{2\baselineskip}
\newlength{\mylens}
\setlength{\mylens}{13pt}

\usepackage{arydshln}
%\usepackage{showframe} % for testing purpose only 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]% it's better to avoid H positioning
        \centering
        \label{augSystem}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2} 
        %\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccM{.3cm}c@{}}
            $
            \begin{array}{|M{.8cm}:M{.7cm}:M{.7cm}:M{.7cm}:M{.7cm}:M{.7cm}:M{.7cm}|}
                \hline
                 & A & -b  & \bar{b}  &            &          & \\
                \hdashline\mystrut
                 -A^{T}      &             & c   & -\bar{c} & I      &          & \\[\mylen] 
                \hdashline
                b^{T}        & -c          &            & -\alpha   &          & -1       & \\ 
                \hdashline
                -\bar{b}^{T} & \bar{c}^T & \alpha    &            &                    &&\\ 
                \hdashline\mystrut
                -\bar{b}^{T} & S      &            &            & I       &        &  \\[\mylen]
                \hdashline
                &              & \rho      &            &            & \kappa &          \\ \hdashline
                &              &             & \nu      &            &          & \theta      \\ \hline
            \end{array}
            $
            &
            $
            \begin{array}{|M{.7cm}|}
                \hline
                y \\
                \hdashline
                \myvsp x \\[\mylens]
                \hdashline
                y \\ 
                \hdashline
                v \\ 
                \hdashline
                \myvsp z \\[\mylens] 
                \hdashline
                a \\ 
                \hdashline
                b \\ 
                \hline
            \end{array}
            $
            &
            $=$ 
            &
            $
            \begin{array}{|M{.7cm}|}
                \hline
                r_{1} \\ 
                \hdashline
                \myvsp r_{2} \\[\mylens]
                \hdashline
                r_{3} \\ 
                \hdashline
                r_{4} \\ 
                \hdashline
                \myvsp r_{5} \\[\mylens] 
                \hdashline
                r_{6} \\ 
                \hdashline
                r_{7} \\ 
                \hline
            \end{array}
            $
            \\  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have another small question. Is there a way to center all the elements both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: I do need the rows to be of different heights

Comment: @Morpheus See the new version of my answer, let me know if it could be good for you, thank you!