# Why does adding \\[...] at the end of a row mess up the alignment?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, arydshln

I was trying to reply to the OP's comment at [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364648/101651) but I've found out that when I put `[...]` at the end of a row it messes up the horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}  
Without space added:

\begin{tabular}{|M{.7cm}|}
    \hline
    $y$ \\ 
    \hdashline
    $a$ \\
    \hdashline
    $b$ \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10pt} with space added:

\begin{tabular}{|M{.7cm}|}
    \hline
    $y$ \\[2ex] 
    \hdashline
    $a$ \\
    \hdashline
    $b$ \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

See the position of the `y`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently the space character between `y` and `\\[2ex]` screws the alignment up, it does not occur however, if you incorporate the math mode into the `M` column type

Comment: It's a known feature of the `m` column type. I bet this is a duplicate.

Comment: @egreg: It does not occur without the `arydshln` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right (both statements)! If you'd like to write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Rather not, it's removing the symptom but not the cause (Frank N'Furter ;-))

Comment: @egreg Christian is right, it doesn't happen without `arydshlin` package. I've searched but I haven't found a duplicate...

Comment: @egreg you are thinking of a different "feature" of the m-type. This is a bug in arydshln package missing the \unskip (as Ulrike pointed out)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the space after the math. `arydshln` redefines internal commands (in this case `\@xargarraycr`) and forgot the `\unskip` from the original definition:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}

\begin{tabular}{|M{.7cm}|}
    \hline
    $y$ \\[2ex]
    \hdashline
    $a$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|M{.7cm}|}
    \hline
    $y$\\[2ex] %no problem without the space
    \hdashline
    $a$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@xargarraycr{\unskip}{}{\fail} %patch to add \unskip

\begin{tabular}{|M{.7cm}|}
    \hline
    $y$ \\[2ex]
    \hdashline
    $a$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in addition that package does miss a lot of % signs,  so it adds spaces in other places (usually harmless but I wouldn't be surprised if some of them gives extra spaces in the output. if you turn on \tracingall you will see a lof of `blank space` (none of which should be there).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I saw only a few suspicious `\noalign{`, one missing % in `\adl@def@extract` and one in `\adl@LTixhline`. Are there more?

Comment: there are more, though I haven't really traced them all: \adl@@cr (2 missing), \adl@hline (first line needs \relax). There may be others, once I saw the \unskip missing I didn't really look further

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Oh yes, you are right. It is really easy to overlook this spurious spaces ;-).

Comment: this is why I really like the expl3 conventions of not having any space count unless you epxlicitly put it in as a tilde ... much more readable and much less likely to cause harm

Comment: @FrankMittelbach me too, it is really a relief to be able to indent the code in a meaningful way without having to add the damn percent signs everywhere.